# set xtics by <start>, <incr> in gnuplot does not work

Tags: gnuplot

I plot with gnuplot the following:

```
$Data <<EOD

time_,value

1-23:59:58,1

1-23:59:59,2

2-00:00:00,3

2-00:00:01,4

2-00:00:02,5

EOD

set term png  size 800,600 

set output "ask.png"

set datafile separator comma

set grid

set xdata time

set timefmt "%d-%H:%M:%S" 

set format x "%H:%M:%S" 

set xtics nomirror

set autoscale xfix

set autoscale x2fix

startnumber=1

xticdata=2

mxticdata=2

set xtics xticdata rotate

set mxtics mxticdata

set x2data

set x2tics startnumber, xticdata rotate

set mx2tics mxticdata

set link x2 via x+1 inverse x-1


plot $Data using 1:2 title columnheader(2)

set output
```

Data of the column 2 which contains nearly 50,000 records is value of a parameter. `set link` has to be used to align x-axis and x2-axis. And I want to show x2tic labels for counter/index which must be related to the time(column 1).

The output is alright, but you can see from the attached figure that the labels on x2-axis are big numbers, which is not what I want. I want to get labels like "1,3,5...".

So what's wrong with my code? And how to correct it? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is that the x2 axis should be labeled with the content of column 2 regardless of its numerical relationship to column 1, then you can use:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%H:%M:%S" 
set format x "%H:%M:%S" 
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics nomirror

set link x2

plot $Data using 1:2:x2ticlabels( int($0+1)%2 ? strcol(2) : "" )  title columnheader(2)
```

This creates one x2 axis tick label for every data point. The even-numbered ones to blank and the odd-numbered ones are set to whatever is in column 2.

Comment: Thank you @Ethan. Based on your idea, as the column 2 is not for index/counter, I tried like this: `plot $Data using 1:2:x2ticlabels( int($0+1)%xticdata==1 ? startnumber + xticdata * int($0) : "" )`. But this does not work. What's wrong with this plot command?

Comment: The content of xticlabels should be a string.  your command mixes numbers and strings and would I think produce an error message about string operations using non-string data.  If you want to create a string from a numerical expression, use the `sprintf` function to format it.

Comment: `plot $Data using 1:2:x2ticlabels( int($0+1)%2 ?...` is a good and clear method. In this way, each x2tic is on x2-axis. As there are nearly 50,000 data points in my project which causes too many x2tics on x2-axis. Is there a better way to show x2tics at an interval?

Answer (score 1):

the quickest fix would be

```
set link x2 via x-86397 inverse x+86397
```

But it depends what timesteps you have and what numbers you have in column 2. If your time step it is strictly regular and 1 second, and column 2 just counts up, then column 2 is redundant.
Timedata is handled internally as seconds from 01.01.1970 00:00:00.
One day has 86400 seconds. Check `help time/date`.

Comment: I  set only x-axis as time format, not x2-axis. Why does `set xdata time` influence format of x2data? Is it a bug of gnuplot? As data of my project in column 1/2 can not be predicted, is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: And in accordance with the manuel of gnuplot, "If no option is specified, the data interpretation reverts to normal"(refer to the section of xdata in manuel). But in my example, `set x2data` seems not work. Why?

Comment: you link x1 and x2 axis. As I said, for gnuplot time is in seconds from 01.01.1970. So, that's why x2-axis starts with `86398` which corresponds to `01.01.1970 23:59:58? It's just a different representation. And actually, what is column 2? Just a counter/index or actually data? Please describe in more detail what data you have (I guess thousands of datapoints, not just these 5) and what the final plot result should be.

Comment: Data of the column 2 which contains nearly 50,000 records is value of a parameter, not counter/index. set link has to be used to align x-axis and x2-axis. And I want to show x2tic labels for counter/index which must be related to the time(column 1) at the same interval as xticlabels.